# reading a text file from within a Jar on a remote device

Tags: java, file, jar

Having researched this issue extensively here & elsewhere, without finding a *working* solution, I thought I'd ask...

I have a jar file (deployed on a RaspberryPi), with an internal structure like this:

- myApp

  - MyClass
  - ....
- textFiles

  - foo.txt
  - ....

I need 'MyClass' to read 'foo.txt'.

the general advice here & elsewhere is to use something like the following:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("../textFiles/foo.txt"); 
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

I have also read that the path to use (as the param for *getResourceAsStream()*) is  the path to the target file, *relative* to the location of the class reading the file.(..?)

However, regardless of the path I use, I cannot get the above 2 lines to work. I always get an NPE thrown by the 2nd line.

I'm assuming that the NPE indicates that 'in' is null because 'foo.txt' has not been found.

any advice leading to a successful resolution, gratefully received.

cheers

Paul

Comment: you need to make sure path to the file is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `..` from the path, as per [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)):

- If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
- Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
  `modified_package_name/name`
  Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

Comment: I'm getting nowhere here... I havce tried (based on the jar structure above)...

Comment: I'm getting nowhere here... I have tried (based on the jar structure above): "../textFiles/foo.txt", "/textFiles/foo.txt", "textFiles/foo.txt", "/foo.txt" & , "foo.txt".All not found. (and yes.. the file & directory names are correct)

Answer (score 0):

So my immediate problem has been solved, but not to my satisfaction.

I relocated the contents of 'textFiles' (in the Jar), so all the text files were in the Jar's root. I then successfully managed to find & load the file using:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/foo.txt");
```

However, I still don't undserstand why this worked. I don't see why "/textFiles/foo.txt" didn't work, when the files were in that subdir, off the Jar's root...?

Anyway...I have a new problem now, which I think is hardware related....it takes about 40 seconds to read the files!! I think I blame the old SD card in my Raspberry Pi.

But that's a problem for another day!

Thanks for your input.